# What does "Ad" and "Soyad" mean on a Turkish visa application?

Tags: visas, applications, turkey, working-visas, german-citizens

I have two first names (or a first name and a middle name if you will) and one family name. On the Turkish visa application, there are three name fields:

- *Ad* (translated as "Name")
- *Soyad* (translated as "Surname")
- *Diğer Soyadı(Varsa)* (translated as "Other Surname (if applicable)")

[image: Turkish version of the input form with fields "Ad", "Soyad", and "Diğer Soyadı(Varsa)"]

[image: English version of the input form with fields "Name", "Surname", and "Other Surname (if applicable)"]

Passports and ID Cards generally only have two name fields, Given Name and Surname. Am I correct in assuming that I need to enter *both* my Given Names into the "Ad" field the same way they are recorded in my birth certificate, passport, ID card, and driver's license? My surname obviously goes into the "Soyad" field with the third field left empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

Your "Jörg" and the name starts with "W" should belong on the "Ad" (Name) field (seperated with a space of course) and "Mittag" should belong on the "Soyad" (Surname) field.

Here an example of an e-Visa which is probably the same as with the normal visa application.

[image]